# Get facebook "Photos by Others" with graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am able to get images from my Facebook page no problem, but only images uploaded by page admins.

https://graph.facebook.com/tofinobc/photos/

What I want to get is all images uploaded "by others" - Images posted to the page by fans.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Yes I just verified that you are correct in stating that the photos in the /photo connection are only photos put there by the page and page admins.  However for photos that users upload to the page, they're not there, because the live in a different album:

`fql?q=SELECT pid, object_id,src_big, link, caption FROM photo WHERE pid IN(SELECT pid from photo_tag WHERE subject='PAGE_ID')`

Somehow when uploaded to a page, facebook "tags" the page in the album.  Strange, eh?