# Facebook API: Move Fan Photos from "Fan Photos" album to another album

Tags: php, facebook, api, photo, facebook-page

I am administrator of a Facebook Fan Page and I want to make an application that moves (or copies) photos uploaded by my page's fans to another page's album created by me.

I have never used Facebook APIs. Is it possible to get all fan's photos? Is it possible to save photos to my page's album?

Comment: you can try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841367/get-facebook-photos-by-others-with-graph-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can get the pictures in your fan's page by issuing a GET request to
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/photos. it returns an array (JSON encoded) of the page's picture. You can have an idea of this [here](https://graph.facebook.com/platform/photos?access_token=2227470867%7C2.YGmESRC_cMhuyctReiunjA__.3600.1301605200-1191072317%7CfA051Nu7TZ_1oxn1ljaQ04FIN_U)

Similarly, once you have those picture information you can send them to
https://graph.facebook.com/PROFILE_ID/ALBUM_ID
What tecnology are you going to use for this application?

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/photos returns my page's profile pictures, not fan's photos :(
i think that i'll use PHP or Java (if possible)

Comment: Well, you should then locate the album_id where the photos are located and then use https://graph.facebook.com/ALBUM_ID/photos to retrive all the picture in there. You can actually get all the albums relatively to a user/page going to https://graph.facebook.com/USER_OR_PAGE_ID/albums

Comment: man i am not searching photos in albums that i created or in my page's profile pictures: i need "fan photos" and they are not in graph.facebook.com/USER_OR_PAGE_ID/albums :(